# How to add minutes in DateTime value from SQL Server to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a `DateTime` value from SQL Server and I want to deduct 3 minutes from it.

```
TableA (DateUpdated); -- table in SQL Server
```

Then I have this code in my C# code-behind file.

`lblDateUpdated` is the id of the label for the column `DateUpdated`

```
 protected void grvC_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == grvC.EditIndex)
        {
            DateTime dtUpdated = new DateTime();
            value2 = ((TextBox)(grvClients.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].FindControl("lblDateUpdated"))).Text.ToString().Trim();
            dtUpdated = Convert.ToDateTime(value2);
            dtUpdated = dtUpdated.AddMinutes(-3);
         }
     }
}
```

The error it show is this:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

on the line

```
value2 = ((TextBox)(grvClients.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].FindControl("lblDateUpdated"))).Text.ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: What is that square bracket doing at the end of the line? Also what is value2?

Comment: Why not get the label column directly instead of looking for the control? Any reason you are doing that?

Comment: It's the convention already from the existing code.

Comment: I missed that this was ASP. Sorry. Still, it's more convoluted than it needs to be. Looks like @mybirthname's answer may work.

Comment: @TomJerry Is lblDateUpdated a label or textbox?

Comment: @SILENT it's a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @mybirthname's sample.
If its a label, try

```
if (e.Row.DataItem == null)
   return;

var lb = e.Row.FindControl("lblDateUpdated") as Label;
var value = ((string)lb.Content).Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take the label from `GridViewRowEventArgs` .

```
if (e.Row.DataItem == null)
      return;

 TextBox textBox = e.Row.FindControl("lblDateUpdated") as TextBox;
 string value = textBox.Text.Trim();
```

Comment: why make it a TextBox?

Comment: after making it a string can I able to make the deduction of minutes possible?

Comment: string value = textBox.Text.Trim(); //error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: what is the control is it TextBox ? Are you sure this is the correct ID of the control ?