# ASP.net c# how to parse the value of datetime to deduct minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I have this code:

```
if (e.Row.DataItem == null)
  return;
TextBox textBox = e.Row.FindControl("lblDateUpdated") as TextBox;
string value = textBox.Text.Trim();
```

I want to deduct minutes from the `"lblDateUpdated"` which is a `DateTime` value . How would I able to parse it to deduct minutes from it?

Comment: what is your date format? (in lblDateUpdated)

Comment: Use DateTime.TryParse. To deduct minutes, use DateTime's AddMinutes.

Comment: I have this question connected to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708740/how-to-add-minutes-in-datetime-value-from-mssql-to-aspx-cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your TextBox.Text contains the string your desire. Check using a breakpoint or a variable watcher.

Then use the following code:

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse(value, out dt))
{
      double minutesToDeduct = -3;
      dt.AddMinutes(minutesToDeduct);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string value to DateTime by [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)
Then adds the negative int value using [DateTime.AddMinutes(-int value)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am trying this : //DateTime dt;
                         //DateTime.TryParseExact(value,"yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out dt); but there is error